# How to close the div again when it is triggered by on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this jquery code which loads more content from hidden div i got it to open and everything works smooth but i want it to close again but i don't know how to do it.
i also want to change loadmore to close when it is open...

Help
html:

```
<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>  

$(function () {
    $("moreinfo").slice(0, 4).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
        if ($("div:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.totop a').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.totop a').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Update:

```
    $(function () {
        $("div").slice(0, 4).show();
        $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".moreinfo:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();

        });
        $(".loadLess").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".moreinfo:visible ").slice(0, 4).slideUp();

        });
    });
```

this will allow it to open and close right away auto...

Comment: Again, if you look at my example, you'll notice I am selecting .slice(-4) aka the LAST 4 elements and hide them (slideUp). The way you have loadLess implementing, you are hiding and showing the 4 FIRST elements instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function gets the first 4 elements which are hidden and display:block them with the slideDown function. If you want to hide them again, you need to have a reference to these elements BEFORE the slideDown function. Or, if this is appropriate in your html structure, take the last 4 visible div elements and hide them.

So, a function like

```
$("#loadLess").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div:visible").slice(-4).slideUp();
});
```

In this case, you will need to have an element that will trigger this function to run, most probably at the end of the visible divs

```
  <a id="loadLess">Show less</a>
```

Having said that, selectors like div:visible or div:hidden are due to cause troubles. You should use some specific class attribute for that, like .contentitems:hidden or something

Edit:
[Here's a fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hQUx8/) to see it working

and this is the code used in the jsfiddle

```
<div class="someclass">some content 1 </div>
<div class="someclass">some content 1 </div>
<div class="someclass">some content 1 </div>
<div class="someclass">some content 1 </div>
<div class="someclass">some content 1 </div>

.....
<span id="loadMore">Load More</span>
<span id="loadLess">Load Less</span>
```

js

```
$('div').slice(0, 4).show();
$("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
        if ($("div:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });

$("#loadLess").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div:visible").slice(-4).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: somehow now it opens and closes right away fast right away

Comment: When i click load more: it loads more and also it closes automatically... 

i can't seem to go around it

Comment: The issue was that i used the same <a> and give it id and class but i was supposed to do it each independently. 

Thanks for help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using `toggle()`

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Here is an example on how you can use it:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPF63/)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the example provided, he (possibly more than once) adds 4 more elements with each click. Toggle what?

Comment: @alou He asked how to close a open div and toggle() is a solution for that.

Comment: No, in this case it's not. Again, what elements would you toggle?